# Translate and publish in English

Tags: publishing, translation

I authored a bicycle traveloque in regional language Malayalam, which is well accepted by readers and three editions of the book have come out yet. I want to translate book into English, German & Russian and publish ? who can help me for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you live, you can find one or more language translators. For example, in Delhi / Mumbai you'll easily find translators whereas in Kerala, you **may not** find Russian translators. No matter what you do, English translation should be relatively easy but quality is inconsistent.

They'll charge you on per hour basis or fixed cost, depending on individuals. I am not too aware of professional translation services by companies but they might exist as well in Delhi / Mumbai.

You'll need to have a clear agreement with them to maintain your copyright but credit them too for their work.

Consider Malayalam-English first. You can always get English-Russian & English-German translation later.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to have to find someone (or probably more than one) person in India that can translate the work into English, German and Russian. The cost of translators is probably going to be much lower there than it is in say England and America. Also, it will be much easier to find someone who can do it, I think.